# How do I determine if my kernel uses initramfs?

Tags: initramfs

I'm reading up on [Wake on Lan on Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/WakeOnLan) and there is a part that says:

> If your kernel uses an initramfs image (eg. Debian stock kernels), also run `update-initramfs -u` (or `update-initramfs -u -k all` if necessary) to rebuild kernel initial ramdisk(s).

How do I determine if my kernel uses initramfs?

I installed LMDE v2, 64-bit, Mate.

Comment: Your computer boots.

Comment: "Your computer boots" - true for most mainstream distros, but not universally true. I had a gentoo box with no initrd/initramfs for a decade and it worked flawlessly. Of course this limits the choices around filesystem, encryption, lvm etc. But it is still seen in the wild.

Answer (score 4):

While terse, mikeserv is essentially correct - Linux has used `initramfs` for a long time, since the 2.6 days. If you use GRUB (which, assuming you have a default LMDE installation, you do), then checkout `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
$ grep initr /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-53-generic
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-53-generic
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
```

Even though the name is `initrd`, it is an `initramfs` archive, which you can test by virtue of `initramfs` being a CPIO archive:

```
$ file - < /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
/dev/stdin: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Tue Sep 30 20:07:43 2014
$ gunzip < /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

(The name for the `initramfs` image is distro-dependent. Arch Linux, for example, simply calls it `initramfs-linux.img`.)

Comment: It's not just typical - initramfs is a filesystem. The image which accompanies most kernels is unpacked into that fs at boot. If there is no external image file, then it is because the required image has been compiled into the kernel itself. In both cases the kernel mounts its first root as an initramfs at boot. This has been the case since the 2.6 kernel series - it is a requirement for every linux kernel since.

Comment: @mikeserv Odd. Everything I've read (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs, https://wiki.debian.org/initramfs/More, https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt) seems to indicate that the primary quality of `initramfs` is that it is *not* a filesystem image, unlike `initrd`. Probably just a technical difference.

Comment: Well. Yes and no - it's not an image *of* a filesystem, because initramfs *is* one whereas the initrd is a *filesystem* image laid down on a ram disk - a block dev. But initramfs is basically tmpfs - it's fs cache incarnate - so there's no underlying block layer at all, and the initramfs image *(or archive may be more correct to say)* can just be a simple cpio stream archive. But my point was that external archive/image file or no - initramfs is *not* optional.

Comment: @mikeserv Done. But in case the initramfs is compiled into the kernel, how do we detect it?

Comment: Detect it? I guess you wouldn't - unless you stuck a debugger in there and did like `init=bin/gdb` on the kernel commandline. It's *there* though - it's the kernel's first root every time. See [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt) for the whole story.

Comment: @mikeserv [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=Extract_initramfs_from_zImage) seems to search the decompressed kernel for some kinda signature to extract the `cpio` archive.

Comment: that's too much x86 centric. doesn't work on mips, arm, even x86 qemu, and every system that doesn't use grub.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all Linux desktop uses initramfs at least with default configuration including LMDE v2 and initramfs feature is kernel inbuilt.

Some OS like Slitaz and many embedded system OS like OpenWRT do not use initramfs image, they skips the initramfs image during boot, by a kernel boot argument `noinitrd`. you can check it at your bootloader(GRUB) menu or after booting, run

`cat /proc/cmdline` if you see a `noinitrd` word then it do not use initramfs image. There is a near 100% chance you will not see `noinitrd` word.

Answer (score 0):

If an `initramfs` (or `initrd` for that matter) has been used during boot, the logs should have a bunch of `initrd` related entries.

Examples from my `Arch Linux` box:

```bsh
$ sudo dmesg -T | grep "initrd"
[Tue Feb 15 12:58:58 2022] Freeing initrd memory: 31360K
```

or, using `journalctl`

```bsh
$ journalctl -b --no-hostname | grep "initrd"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Feb 15 12:58:22 kernel: Freeing initrd memory: 31360K
Feb 15 12:58:29 systemd[1]: initrd-parse-etc.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 15 12:58:29 systemd[1]: initrd-cleanup.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 15 12:58:29 systemd[1]: initrd-udevadm-cleanup-db.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 15 12:58:30 systemd[1]: initrd-switch-root.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 15 13:00:00 systemd[1]: Startup finished in 16.502s (firmware) + 5.955s (loader) + 751ms (kernel) + 7.451s (initrd) + 1min 30.238s (userspace) = 2min 900ms.
```